# XHR error 404 while importing node module - Angular-2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, typescript-typings

I have directory structure as:

```
dir
   |--app.component.ts

  node_modules
  |--angular2-bootstrap-switch
```

I follow https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-bootstrap-switch to add angular2-boostrap switch and as per instruction, I had to do but, I ain't sure how.

index.html:

```
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>

<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>


<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script>
  System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }

    }
  });


     System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
```

Inside boot.ts

```
 import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

IN tsconfig.json

```
 "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
```

Now i have to import ../node_modules/angular2_bootstrap_switch/components inside app.component.ts,like:

```
import {SwitchComponent} from angular2_bootstrap_switch/components
```

I ain't sure how. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this is very simple.

1. Install the node_module

   ```
   npm i angular2-bootstrap-switch
   ```
2. In your system Js add the configuration as,

   ```
   'angular2-bootstrap-switch':'npm:angular2-bootstrap-switch/lib/switch.component.js'
   ```
3. In your App Module import the Switch Component as

   ```
   import {SwitchComponent} from 'angular2-bootstrap-switch'
   ```
4. Add it to declarations as below,

   ```
   declarations: [ SwitchComponent ],
   ```
5. Use it in your HTML as

   ```
   <switch [status]="value" [onText]="onText" [offText]="offText" 
           [onColor]="onColor" [offColor]="offColor" [size]="size">
   </switch>
   ```

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/lGPYXuZtdno1CAA27FfP?p=preview)

Comment: HI, thanks for your effort. I face an issue here . FIrst i did npm install angular2-bootstrap-switch and did most of the steps. I got XHR 404 while loading switch. Later i uninstalled angular2-bootstrap-switch and then did npm i angular2-bootstrap-switch and now I get cannot find module angular2-bootstrap-switch. I ain't sure what so fishy, Please clarify.

Comment: are you available in teamviewer?

Comment: Yes i have but this is for a startup. Is it fine?

Comment: @Gayathri posted and deleted a question i guess

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148153/room-for-gayathri-and-aravind